# Connect to SQL Server on other PC

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to make my program, that uses SQL Server, available on another machine.  I know that that machine will need the SQL Server Client installed for this to work, but I am wondering if my ConnectionString will work outside of my own PC.

Do I need to attach my Database to the Project? And if so, how could I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\BENESQL;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123qwe;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your connection string points to the *local* machine. Use the remote machine's name or address as a data source instead

Comment: The connection string will work on another machine provided the credentials are correct.  I recommend using : tring="Data Source=.\BENESQL;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=true;"  Integerated Security will use a windows credential which will work if 1)local PC and Remove PC are is the same group 2) A Group Account is setup on local and remote PC 3) The user(s) are added to the Group Account.  Usually a company has Group Policies Setup and the Groups are already established.  Talk to your MIS people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data source must contain either other PC name or IP address, so instead of:

```
Data Source=.\BENESQL
```

you need something like:

```
Data Source=123.123.123.123\BENESQL
```

Also you need to remember to add exceptions to firewall etc.

Comment: I'm not trying to access it through a network. I just want the other PC to have it's own Database localy. Would I just do something like: Data Source="Natalie'sPC\BeneSQL" if I for instance wanted to have it on a PC with that name?

Comment: If you decide to setup database and application on other PC then .\ will work properly as 127.0.0.1\ would.

Answer (score 5):

Your connection string is pointing at your local machine, change it to:

```
connectionString="Data Source=<<server name or IP address>>\BENESQL;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123qwe;"
```

By default SQL server is not setup to be connected to remotely, even if it's not your LAN. On your server you need to go on to Sql Server Configuration Manager and enable `TCP/IP`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No it will not since it's currently pointing to a local instance of SQL server. You would also need to specify the server ip and port probably in your `Data Source` property of connection string

```
Data Source=<IPAddress>\BENESQL;Initial Catalog=Northwind;
```

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for more information